# Como comparar "float" com "null"?

Tags: java, tipagem, null

```
public class NuloOuNao {
    public static boolean isZero(float num) {
        if(num == null) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        isZero(10);
    }
}
```

> Linha 5: The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) float, null

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java possui tipos por valor como é o caso de `float`. Esses tipos não podem ser nulos. Mas Java criou tipos por referência, ou seja, tipos criados como classes, equivalentes aos tipos primitivos. Então existe o tipo [`Float`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html). Ele é essencialmente igual ao `float`, mas é um objeto isolado. Ele é bem menos eficiente em todos os sentidos, mas possui um valor nulo natural.

```
public class NuloOuNao {
    public static boolean isZero(Float num) {
        return num == null;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        isZero(10);
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/PrimitiveNull.java).

Pense bem se precisa disto mesmo. Este código parece fazer algo enganoso. Nulo e zero são coisas bem diferentes.

[image: Papel higiênico vazio e sem rolo]